# how to retrieve variable from main into a new class

Tags: java

im trying to use the variable "box" that i have the user set in the two following classes.the program prints out a row of boxes. the amount of boxes is determined by the user. would also like some input to see if i am doing this right. or if there is a better solution to the problem.

```
+------+  
|      |  
|      |   
+------+   

import java.util.*;

public class project1 {
 public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Project  1 written by Mario Torres");
  int box;
  int count;
  System.out.println("Enter Number Of Box:");
    box = CONSOLE.nextInt();
  System.out.println(" the amount of boxs is" +box);
    for (count=1; count>0;count=(count-box)){
      System.out.print("+");
      topAndBottom( );
      System.out.print("|" );
      virticalLine( );
      System.out.print("|");
      virticalLine( );
      System.out.print("+");
      topAndBottom( );
    }

    System.out.println();
}
    public static void topAndBottom( ){
    for (int count=1; count <=box; count++){
      System.out.print("------+");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
    public static void virticalLine( ){
    for (int count=1; count<=box; count++){
      System.out.print("      |");
    }
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have only 1 class there.

Comment: At present you have 'box' as a variable defined in main() method. Hence it can be accessed only within the main(). If you want to access this method in topAndBottom() method then you should instead declar the variable 'box' at class level just like you have defined CONSOLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared you variable inside your main method, so you cannot access it from outside of that scope.
You can take the box as parameter in your methods:

```
public static void topAndBottom(int box){}
```

Then call the method like this:

```
topAndBottom(box);
```

Comment: thanks that worked great. i had tried using topAndBottom(box); but forgot to add the Int box. i do still have the problem of when the user input a 0 i get an infinite loop any suggestions there

Comment: Great, if it worked can you accept the answer when you can (15 mins from when you asked the question). You should probably write your for loop again like that it wouldn't do anything if you enter 0.